# The relation between MPI_Comm_split and MPI_Send / MPI_Recv

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

Let's say there are 3 processes, This code works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int rank; MPI_Comm SubWorld; int buf;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    if (rank == 0){
        MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, rank, &SubWorld);
        MPI_Send(&buf, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 55, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else if (rank == 1){
        MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, rank, &SubWorld);
        MPI_Recv(&buf, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 55, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }
    else MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, rank, &SubWorld);

    cout << "Done" << endl;

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs "Done" three times as expected.

But this code has a problem (also 3 processes):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int rank; MPI_Comm SubWorld; int buf;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    if (rank == 0){
        MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, rank, &SubWorld);
        MPI_Send(&buf, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 55, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else if (rank == 1){
        MPI_Recv(&buf, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 55, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, rank, &SubWorld);
    }
    else MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, rank, &SubWorld);

    cout << "Done" << endl;

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

There is no output!!

What exactly is the relation between MPI_Comm_split and MPI_Send / MPI_Recv which cause this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MPI_Comm_split()` is a collective operation, which means all MPI tasks from the initial communicator (e.g. `MPI_COMM_WORLD` here) must invoke it at the same time.

In your example, rank `1` hangs in `MPI_Recv()`, and hence `MPI_Comm_split()` on rank `0` cannot complete (and `MPI_Send()` is never invoked) and hence the deadlock.

You might consider `padb` in order to visualize the state of a MPI program, it would make it easy to see where stacks are stuck at.

Comment: Again, you gave me the answer that I was looking for. Big thanks.